# Make right div be at top instead of at bottom

Tags: css

How do I make the right div be at the top instead of at the bottom?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#all
{
    width: 955px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #F4FEC0;
}
#dleft
{
    margin-right: 200px;
}
#dright
{
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 755px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="all">    
    <div id="dleft">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec et odio elit. Praesent ut sem nibh, non ultricies purus. Integer viverra dapibus nulla. Nulla quis quam mauris, et faucibus arcu. Integer quis est a libero lacinia tincidunt. Duis dignissim dui nec quam vehicula nec eleifend dolor scelerisque. Cras vehicula, mauris quis pretium gravida, justo tellus tincidunt nunc, faucibus euismod enim sapien at neque. Fusce quis elit ut elit commodo pulvinar id sit amet urna. Mauris sapien lacus, auctor eu posuere at, mattis in elit. Sed congue ultricies diam, sit amet placerat quam rutrum ac. Vivamus pellentesque tristique nisi, a consectetur sem dignissim in. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc rhoncus dolor nibh. In ornare mattis lectus, id mattis felis iaculis vel. Maecenas quis tellus eu est luctus mattis eu id urna. Vestibulum eu elit eget magna malesuada adipiscing. Vestibulum sem neque, condimentum eget luctus vel, rhoncus vel tellus. Donec egestas quam id erat dignissim tempus. Cras volutpat erat ac enim fermentum eu convallis quam porttitor. Quisque ac tellus sit amet libero interdum sodales.
    </div>
    <div id="dright">
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
        menu<br />
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind moving around some of your HTML, this is an easy solution:

From `#dright`, remove the `margin-left` property.

In the HTML, move `<div id="dright">` to before `<div id="dleft">`.

To `#all`, add `overflow: auto` - this is required to [clear the float](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) if your right `<div>` becomes higher than your left.

Answer (score 3):

```
#dleft
{
   float:left;
    width:755px;
}
#dright
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#dright
{
    position:absolute;
    left:775px;
    top:0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dleft` div doesn't have a `width` set and will therefore try to fill the whole of it's container. Either set a `width` for `dleft`, seeing as the width of the container is 955px then this should be no more than 755px, or have `position:absolute; top:0;` in the CSS for `dright`.